# How to setup docker-compose to work with app engine and wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, docker, google-app-engine

I am using gitlab ci/cd to deploy my app to google app engine. I already have php instance working properly but when i try build wordpress image using docker-compose, nothing happen.

these are my files:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a folder "web" with a files ping.php: https://site-dot-standalone-applications.appspot.com/ping.php

So application is running into /web folder.

wordpress should be deployed into /web folder after:

> docker-compose up

**UPDATE**
Just needed use the following gitlab-ci.yaml:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot (easily) deploy containers to App Engine Flex this way.

At its simplest, App Engine Flex is a service that combines a load-balancer, an auto-scaler and your docker image. Your image when run as a container is expected to provide an HTTP/S endpoint on port 8080.

There are 2 ways that App Engine could support your deployment **but** it does neither:

- It bundles a WordPress app image and a MySQL image into a single "pod" and exposes WordPress' HTTP port on `:8080`. This isn't what you want because then each WordPress instance has its own MySQL instance.
- It separates the WordPress app into one service and the MySQL app into another service. This is closer to what you want as you could then scale the WordPress instances independently of the MySQL instances. However, databases are the definitive stateful app and you don't want to run these as App Engine services.

The second case suggests some alternative approaches for you to consider:

1. Deploy your WordPress app to App Engine but use Google Cloud SQL service [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql).
2. If you don't want to use Cloud SQL, you could run your MySQL database on Compute Engine [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql).
3. You may wish to consider Kubernetes Engine. This would permit both the approaches outlined above and there are tools that help you migrate from docker-compose files to Kubernetes configurations [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/).

Since you're familiar with App Engine, I recommend you consider using option #1 above (Cloud SQL)

Comment: Thanks, i will follow your with cloud sql. But what about wordpress web site? it should be compiled into app-engine exposing port 8080 as describe in my docker-compose or it didnt worked because of mysql image?

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately the official WordPress image uses port 80 (hence the port mapping `8080:80` in your docker-compose file) and so this can't be used directly on App Engine Flex. You may wish to review this: https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible

Comment: It worked now. I used google platform git sample project to start wordpress and i have it running now. It look be expensive o.o I will accept your answer and i will update post with the latest gitlab-ci.yaml